# How to use a fixed cell in a formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with using a formula that contains a fixed cell in VBA. The issue comes when the row number of the variable in the new data changes.
The issue is explained using a simple example as follow. I hope you find it understandable.
Let's say I have a column of numbers (Time) and I want to multiply them by a variable in a cell (The cell below Variable in the following table, $A$2).

First result from first raw data:
[image: First result from first raw data]

The results in the table are calculated using the following formula `"=R2C1*RC[-1]"` in vba
[image: VBA formula used]
Now in the next calculation, the row number and variable change and the part of the formula which is using a fixed cell cause problem.
Second raw data to be processed

[image: second raw data to be processed]
Because it does not update the row number and use the old row number. I want it to find its location like the second part of the formula (B2 changes to B7).
Thank you for your help!
Cheers,
Aryan

Comment: Please do not post images of code and formulas. Code & formulas should be included between code tags (paste code in, highlight, ctrl & k). Data - consider a  [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reference the found cell row in your formula

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & ActiveCell.Row + 1 & "C1*RC[-1]"
```

but you should also avoid the Activate/ActiveXXX/Select/Selection pattern since is prone to have you quickly lose control over the actually *active* thing

finally you an use a loop to find all "Time" occurrences (see [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel) for more info about the pattern)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim f As Range, firstCell As Range
    With Worksheets("myWorksheetName") ' reference your worksheet (change myWorksheetName to your actual sheet name)
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) 'reference its column B cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            Set f = .Find("Time", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'search referenced range for first occurrence of "time"
            If Not f Is Nothing Then ' if found...
                Set firstCell = f ' store first occurrence cell
                Do
                    f.Offset(1, 1).Resize(4).FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & f.Row + 1 & "C1*RC[-1]" ' populate the range one column to the right of found cell and 4 rows wide with the formula containg the reference of found cell row +1
                    Set f = .FindNext(f) ' serach for the next "Time" occurrence
                Loop While f.Row <> firstCell.Row ' loop till you wrap back to initial occurrence
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The notation `R2C1` is an absolute reference to row 2, column 1.

If you want a reference that is relative to the current cell, you need to use relative reference notation.

`RC[-1]` points to a cell in the current row and one column to the left

`R[1]C` points to a cell one row down from the current cell and in the same column as the current cell.

Google for "R1C1 reference". You will find many articles, for e.g. https://smurfonspreadsheets.wordpress.com/2007/11/12/r1c1-notation/